# A WMTS layer (Topotijdreis) does not show in Leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, wms, wmts, esri-leaflet

I want to maka a map with the following layer/data. But the map does not show up.
This is the WMTS service: [here](https://tiles1.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Historische_tijdreis_1996/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml)

I am using programming language R and the leaflet package in R. My code looks like this:

```r
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.esri)

epsg28992 <- leafletCRS(
  crsClass = "L.Proj.CRS"
  ,code = "EPSG:28992"
  ,proj4def = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857330322398,0.350732676542563,-1.8703473836068,4.0812 +no_defs"
  ,origin=c(-3.05155E7,3.1112399999999993E7)
  ,resolutions = c(3251.206502413005,1625.6032512065026,812.8016256032513,406.40081280162565,203.20040640081282,101.60020320040641, 50.800101600203206,25.400050800101603,12.700025400050801,6.350012700025401,3.1750063500127004,1.5875031750063502,0.7937515875031751,0.39687579375158755,0.19843789687579377,0.09921894843789689,0.04960947421894844)
)

leaflet(options = leafletOptions(crs = epsg28992)) %>%
  setView(229684.400,513480.640,zoom = 10) %>%
  addEsriTiledMapLayer("https://tiles1.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Historische_tijdreis_1996/MapServer/"
                       ,group = "Layer_1996" 
  )
```

But a grey map shows up.

Can you help me?

Comment: If you also wish to ask a question about Python then please do that in a separate one from this one that uses R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Leaflet in R, but your problem is most probably use of projected coordinates in `setView`.

Regardless of map projection, Leaflet always requires unpprojected coordinates `[lat, lng]` as input to its functions/methods.

This worked for me OK in JS Leaflet:

```
var crs28992 = new L.Proj.CRS(
  'EPSG:28992',
  '+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857330322398,0.350732676542563,-1.8703473836068,4.0812 +no_defs',                        
  {
   origin: [-3.05155E7,3.1112399999999993E7],
   resolutions: [3251.206502413005,1625.6032512065026,812.8016256032513,406.40081280162565,203.20040640081282,101.60020320040641, 50.800101600203206,25.400050800101603,12.700025400050801,6.350012700025401,3.1750063500127004,1.5875031750063502,0.7937515875031751,0.39687579375158755,0.19843789687579377,0.09921894843789689,0.04960947421894844],
  }
);

var map = new L.Map('map', {
  crs: crs28992
}).setView([52, 5], 2);

L.esri.tiledMapLayer({
  url: 'https://tiles1.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Historische_tijdreis_1996/MapServer/'
}).addTo(map);
```